# how do I get SHA-1 certificate in expo?

Tags: expo

Is there a certain command in expo to get the certificate?
All the guide I find are for just react-native which tell me to go to android folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method is changed, for lazy folks like me it is:

`eas credentials`

or

`npx eas-cli credentials`.

Answer (score 23):

Run `expo credentials:manager`

You can check the documentation here
https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-signing/

Comment: The updated command is `eas credentials`.

Comment: is there a way i can get it locally? without eas?

Answer (score 4):

Using the Expo Dashboard, you can log into https://expo.dev/. If you have an existing build, select it.  SHA-1 certificate is under configure -> credentials

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to get the SHA1 hash without eas, you can simply do:

```
cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

Warning there will be many SHA1 hashes, make sure to find the correct one that you need (debug, release, etc...)